# Decoding a message involving RSA public key encryption and polynomials (homework)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem:

[image]

What I've gotten so far:

The prime roots of 1073 are 29 and 37, so $\phi(n) = 28 * 36 = 1008$. We know that $ax + \phi(n)y = 1$, so $605x + 1008y = 1$. I can't find any solutions x and y for this. I wrote a piece of code to scan for x and y, but it returns no results:

```
b = 1008
e = 605
x = 1
y = 1
while x < 1000:
        b = b * x
        while y < 1000:
                e = e * y
                if b % e == 1 or e % b == 1:
                        print e, b
                y += 1
        x += 1
```

I can't figure out what I've done wrong. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You may consider using [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) for this. Btw, the code for "exaustive" search should be `print [(x,y) for x in xrange(-1000,1000) for y in xrange(-1000,1000) if 605*x+1008*y==1]`

Comment: Oh, alrighty, I got it. So then I get 71, 36 --> 1000111, 0100100 --> 100011, 010010 --> 1101, 0110 --> Hi

(such an extremely important message)

Thank you!